# Previous HEAD position was f62c4f3... fail harder, but recover, when wrong line separators are inserted into a document

Tags: git

I just checkout in one of my repositories

```
git checkout -f master
```

and get this

```
Previous HEAD position was f62c4f3... fail harder, but recover, when wrong line separators are inserted into a document
```

Is everything okey in my git repository? Should I do something to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout` is telling you that you were in a "detached HEAD" state. The commit that you were on before had the subject line

> fail harder, but recover, when wrong line separators are inserted into a document

i.e., the scary message is from one of your commit messages.

Your repository is fine. There is nothing to correct.